# RDBMS - what can I do to get query results faster?

Tags: sql, view, rdbms

In a few weeks I am supposed to answear this question. What can I do in my Relational Database to get query answear faster?

My first thought - well planned set of views. But is there anything else I could do????

Comment: Proper indexes for each and every WHERE clause you query with; well-written queries that don't force TABLE SCAN.

Comment: Set up server properly...

Comment: Normalize data, at least 3nf. Avoid joins on string columns....